# DBMS_RANDOM considered dangerous?

Tags: oracle, security

Our database team wants to revoke execute on DBMS_RANDOM from PUBLIC to address security issues. If you google for it, some security experts consider the package dangerous, but fail to say why. Ingram and Shaul's book "Practical Oracle Security" states

> ...granting PUBLIC access to DBMS_RANDOM in environments where the
>   function is used in cryptographic key generation could lead to
>   compromise of the encrypted data...

The Oracle documentation says

> DBMS_RANDOM is not intended for cryptography.

... and ...

> DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES ... returns a RAW value containing a
>   cryptographically secure pseudo-random sequence of bytes, which can be
>   used to generate random material for encryption keys.

So, DMBS_RANDOM seems to be fine for generating pseudorandom numbers (as long as you don't fabricate passwords with it). Why on earth is this too dangerous for PUBLIC?

**Edit**:
Just found a new [source](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/oracle_database_11g_instance/2016-06-15/finding/V-2539), which claims that

> DBMS_RANDOM: allows encrypting of data without requiring safe management of encryption keys.

This is nonsense, too, isn't it?

Comment: seems a bit backwards to me.  If they used dbms_random for cryptographic keys, then they should fix that issue, not revoke grants to dbms_random.  Do they give a reason other than "security issues"?

Comment: No, they don't. I found another source: "... lists the most dangerous packages assigned by default that are assigned to the PUBLIC role..." DBMS_RANDOM: This package can be used to encrypt stored data. Generally, most users should not have the privilege to encrypt data since encrypted data may be non-recoverable if the keys are not securely generated, stored, and managed, etc. http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2012/03/top-10-oracle-steps-to-secure-oracle.html This doesn't make sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why DBMS_RANDOM should not be granted to PUBLIC, when using it for crypto key generation, is that an attacker could use it to determine seed values and/or patterns in the key generation, that could be used to determine the key the data is encrypted with. This is why it could lead to compromise of the encrypted data.  It certainly is not an easy attack, but it is possible for someone with enough processing power.

DBMS_RANDOM should not be used for crypto because it is too predictable.  For crypto key generation, only a secure random function should be used.  These functions attempt to get as random as possible by measuring things like white noise and producing values off of it.

Comment: Interesting. So DBMS_RANDOM is only a security risk IF we have used it for crypto (ignoring the advice against it)? Otherwise, it's perfectly safe, I'd presume.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes, you are correct. Many people ignore (or don't know about) the advice against using it for crypto, so it can be a problem for them

Comment: @Freedom_Ben But why does an attacker need **EXECUTE** on DBMS_PUBLIC? 
The seed is described in the documentation:
>By default, the package is initialized with the current user name, current time down to the second, and the current session. 
<http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_random.htm#sthref7037>

Comment: @wolφi The key to that is "By default."  The seed can be changed, so it isn't necessarily the "current user name, current time down to the second, and the current session."  Also those items' values may not all be known to the attacker.  But yes, that is a poor seed for security.  That's why the docs say not to use it for crypto.

Comment: @Freedom_Ben If the seed is changed, execute on the package doesn't help at all to find the seed. If the seed computed by the documented default method, execute doesn't help either. How does a REVOKE make the database safer?

Comment: @wolφi It doesn't allow the attacker to get the seed simply by running execute once, but by running execute many times and recording the values returned. Using these values, the seed can be brute forced, especially where the seed has low entropy. The security issue revolves around keeping the attacker from being able to "harvest" generated values and identify the pattern, and hence the seed. Sorry if I'm not explaining it very well

Comment: @Freedom_Ben Thanks for your patience! It's still not clear to me, because in case 1) "key generator changes seed", you can run dbms_random as often as you like, without gaining any knowledge about how the seed was set, right? And in case 2) "default seed is used", you don't need to run dbms_random a single time to indentify the pattern, because it is already well documented, right?

Comment: @wolφi 1) That's not quite correct. By running DBMS_RANDOM multiple times and recording the output values, you can run your own generator, incrementing the seed values until your output matches the output of DBMS_RANDOM. At that point you know the seed value (because it's the same one that you were using when it matched the output of DBMS_RANDOM), so you can calculate the crypto keys and anything else that depends on  DBMS_RANDOM.  This attack could take a lot of processing power, so it may not be feasible for a single user.

Comment: A corporate competitor or nation state however, would definitely have the computing power for this type of attack. 2) This is mostly correct. If the default seed is used, and you know the current user name, current (DB) time down to the second, and the current session, then the seed is known and you won't need to run DBMS_RANDOM a single time.  If you don't know one of those values, then you fall back into the same category as your first statement and will need to harvest some outputs so you can match the pattern.

Comment: What do you mean with "until your output matches the output of DBMS_RANDOM"? The attacker can't see the output of the DBMS_RANDOM of the key generating app, as it lives in another session?!?

Comment: Where the seed value is different between sessions, you may be safe.  If it is not, then you are vulnerable.  Also, if the attacker has any of the information that the seed is based off, this lowers the entropy and makes guessing the unknown portion of the seed easier. If the only difference between the seeds is the session value, the attack may be feasible. As you can see the security risk is not terribly high, which is why I believe Oracle lets this stay.

Comment: Using DBMS_RANDOM for generating keys though is still dangerous, even if it's not PUBLIC, because if the DB is compromised through any other means, there is a lot less work required to determine the key due to the low entropy of DBMS_RANDOM

Comment: As a point of interest, this same style of attack was used by some mega hackers back in the day to cheat at Video Poker in Las Vegas.  They bought a machine, pumped values through it millions and millions of times until they found the seed.  The seed was used by the machine to generate the players cards.  By doing this they could predict what cards were coming ahead of time, so they knew when to fold and when to go big.  Since all machines used the same seed, they knew what was coming next on every machine.  Pretty cool story :-)

Comment: So we seem agree on that DBMS_RANDOM should not be used for cryptography and that the security risk of granting it to PUBLIC is not very high. Besides, as the source code of DBMS_RANDOM is publicly available, a hacker would probably run a faster C version outside of the database than the original slower PL/SQL version inside the database, wouldn't he?

Comment: @wolφi Yes, I agree completely.  FWIW I have studied a lot of attacks, and have never heard of one using DBMS_RANDOM.  That does not mean one has never happened, but it's certainly not common.  Great question!