# HASH and SUBSTR in loop PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

_ I want to anonymize the sensitive data of my table with procedure PL SQL. 
_ For this I created a procedure that browses the sensitive data of my table by applying a hash to the data each time.
_ But I want to get a hashed value which the same size as the old value. 
_ So I use the substr() function to cut the hashed value to keep the same size.
_ I have a problem with the splitting of the hashed string for the first value.
for example 
**the first value**
_ Code bic: '??Oh?z+h5?????0?'
_ After hashing 
_ '?Oh?z'

_ I should have '?Oh' instead of '?Oh?z'

**the rest of the result is correct**

_ 'U??Ei???l?ve?<C\n"?'
_ After SUBSTR
_ 'U??'

**here is my source code**

```
create or replace procedure anonymize 
IS
bic_p  varchar(100);
CURSOR c_cursor is select bic from banc;
bic_h raw(15);

BEGIN
 
open c_cursor;

loop
    fetch c_cursor into bic_p;
    exit when c_cursor%notfound;
   dbms_output.put_line('bic: ' || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (dbms_crypto.hash(
            utl_i18n.string_to_raw(bic_p, 'AL32UTF8'),
            dbms_crypto.hash_sh1
          ), 'AL32UTF8'));
    
  dbms_output.put_line('After SUBSTR');
    
    bic_p := SUBSTR(UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (dbms_crypto.hash(
            utl_i18n.string_to_raw(bic_p, 'AL32UTF8'),
            dbms_crypto.hash_sh1
          ), 'AL32UTF8'),
          1,3);
          
    dbms_output.put_line('bic: ' || bic_p);

end loop;

END anonymize;
```

Comment: Question: If you're going to truncate the hash and lose the ability to tell different values apart (even if you don't know what the real values are any more), why hash at all? Why not just replace all of the values with a generic, anonymous value like `ZZZ` and save yourself a lot of what appears to be unnecessary complexity and computing overhead?

Comment: You are right, thank you for your answer. <br> I want to create an anonymize() procedure that iterates through the banc table and anonymizes the bic field in an irreversible way. I wanted to use DBMS_RANDOM.STRING but in the documentation it is written that the DBMS_RANDOM package is not intended for cryptography.

Comment: There's *no* point to cryptography like `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH` if you're throwing away most of the actual hash with `SUBSTR` and you have no intention of *comparing* hash values later on. If all you are doing is *masking* sensitive data, then *ANY* set of characters will do. Using a literal string like `ZZZ` or `***` involves *far* less computing overhead than either `DBMS_RANDOM` or `DBMS_CRYPTO` and accomplishes the same thing: the sensitive data is hidden in a way that can't be reversed.

Comment: I want to create a procedure that replaces a string with another string that has the same length. This string is created randomly and unidirectional.

Comment: I thought of creating an array that contains only alphanumeric values ​​and using the ***DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMNUMBER*** function to retrieve a random number that I will use to retrieve a character from my array. I'm going to use modulo because I can get numbers bigger than my array size.

Comment: I'll ask again: *why do that? What is the problem you are trying to solve?* What is the point of spending the extra compute time on all that data if all you're doing is masking the values? If you want to *remove* the sensitive data, then set the columns to null. If you want to mask it for some people and not others, then best practice is to replace the column value with a literal string using a view or virtual private database, or control access through column-level select permissions.

Comment: What you're describing introduces a lot more compute (especially as a *loop*!) for no practical gain in terms of security, and depending on how much data you're talking about and *how* your function would be used could introduce a *significant* performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that replaces a string with a random string of the same length. It uses `DBMS_RANDOM` which should be fine for this requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function scramble (p_str IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN
    DBMS_RANDOM.STRING (
       opt => 'X',
       len => LENGTH(p_str) );   
END scramble;
/

koen>create table sensitive_data (c1 varchar2(100));

Table SENSITIVE_DATA created.

koen>insert into sensitive_data(c1) values ('secret !');

1 row inserted.

koen>insert into sensitive_data(c1) values ('I have a gazillion bucks');

1 row inserted.

koen>update sensitive_data set c1 = scramble(c1);

2 rows updated.

koen>select * from sensitive_data;

                         C1 
___________________________ 
CRGQ6105                    
93NPDIX7V9XCWKSTTPE0QBI7    

koen>
```

Comment: Technically this does what the OP is apparently trying to do, but I still question the value of doing it: if you're going to mask the data for everyone, better to do it in the actual insert so the real value is never stored. That said, the point of an actual HASH is that the values *are* all the same length, which helps obfuscate the original value. If all that is needed is to indicate a value exists, then a single character replacement should suffice. Preserving the length actually gives away a potentially valuable piece of metadata about the original value and could be considered insecure.

Comment: According to oracle online documentation, DBMS_RANDOM is not intended for cryptography. <br>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970692/dbms-random-considered-dangerous

Comment: @dahidahi By truncating the hash value in your original example, what you're doing isn't cryptography either. Hashing *deliberately* obfuscates the length of the original data but still makes the enumeration of unique values possible. By truncating the hash to match the original length, you lose both of those features and make the use of DBMS_CRYPTO meaningless. Masking too should not expose the original data length; it merely indicates that a value exists, which can be accomplished with a short, literal string that is the same for all values. So *what is the problem you are trying to solve?*

Comment: You talk about the need for cryptography, but if you're not planning to compare the hashed values to something later on to validate an entry against stored data (like a password or a file checksum), or to be able to decrypt an encrypted string (neither of which you seem to need to do), then "cryptography" serves no purpose.

Comment: @pmdba I realize that - but I think that it would perfectly suit the requirement the OP has. As you correctly pointed out it makes more sense to just mask it by replacing the strings completely or partly with stars, but if he wants randomised strings this just does the job.

Comment: @KoenLostrie agreed. i was hoping that the OP could have been more specific with their *underlying* requirement, in which case we could have provided a more useful/precise answer.